# Jets3t on Android

Tags: android, jets3t

I am trying to use the Jets3t library within an Android application, and I keep getting errors with the Rest service when I use the library.

```
04-27 16:47:39.491: ERROR/S3Service(225): Couldn't initialize a sax driver for the XMLReader
```

I have tried to include the Xerces library and the Crimson library, and it dont play well.   I get this error:

```
Attempt to include a core class (java.* or javax.*) in something other
than a core library. It is likely that you have attempted to include
in an application the core library (or a part thereof) from a desktop
virtual machine. This will most assuredly not work. At a minimum, it
jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with future versions of the
platform. It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution,
as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the
"--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
```

Is there something I can do to get it working ?

Comment: You should consider also asking JetS3t-specific questions on the JetS3t Users group (Google Groups) where they are more likely to be seen and answered. Then include the answers in Stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you can work around the SAX driver issue by setting the following system property:

```
System.setProperty("org.xml.sax.driver", "org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver");
```

Credit for this answer goes to Bruno Hautzenberger on the JetS3t User's forum:
http://groups.google.com/group/jets3t-users/browse_thread/thread/d39f32168fd0c217?hl=en

Comment: This Android-specific work around is now implemented in JetS3t directly: http://bitbucket.org/jmurty/jets3t/issue/35/detect-and-use-sax-parser-on-android