# How do you save images to Amazon S3 from android camera?

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3

I am making and app on android that takes pictures using your camera, I then want to save this image to S3, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: This is a two step process: 1. take picture and 2. upload to Amazon S3. Do you have problems with both of this steps?

Answer (score 4):

Taking picture on Android: [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/8683), [here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43414.aspx)

Uploading file to Amazon S3: [here](http://www.peecho.com/blog/2010/9/3/android-upload-to-amazon-s3.html)

Edited: seems that the easiest way to upload to Amazon S3 is [JetS3t](http://bitbucket.org/jmurty/jets3t/wiki/Home). It needs a [little tweak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719257/jets3t-on-android) to work on Android.

Comment: would it be possible to have the android application send a POST request to another web app that allows file uploading(using S3)?

Comment: Amazon S3 is REST, which means that you can POST directly to it.

Comment: Okay thanks I will try it, I am just a bit confused on it. So I should use the HttpUrlConnection api to connect directly to the S3 API? (I dont want to do work with the progress bar..yet)

Comment: Since you need to do a POST you must use HttpClient and HttpPost. Check this example: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientChunkEncodedPost.java

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try to wrap my head around this today.

Answer (score 4):

There is now an Amazon-supported Android SDK: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/ . It's only been out since the end of 2010, but it seems to work well - it allowed me to upload a photo to S3 with 4 lines of code.